# Extract latest zip code from string who contain multiple zip code

Tags: javascript

I would like to extract the lastest zip code (5 digits) from a string who can contain multiple 5 digit. Actually i can extract only the first 5 digits.

```
var add =  '15 castle street BP 44210 41000 NewYork xxx';
var regex = /\d{5}/;
var result = add.match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

I got [44210] as result and i wish [41000]. Sometimes string contains only 1 zip code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the global flag to the regex.

```js
let str = '15 castle street BP 44210 41000 NewYork xxx';
let regex = /\d{5}/g;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```